# What does import database to mysql file Mean

Tags: php, mysql, database

Some time ago I saw this in a YouTube video
Guide us

**1: put the database to MySQL file in db_google.sql**

What does that mean? Does it mean I need to make a new MySQL database? Please help me.

The main post was this:

When people submit something to the website make a new database for that but l don't know how it works l would love if someone could help me in any way
Now this is what someone said

> into the database that you have created then it will allow you to add
> everything in the database.

l cant make a database with that name

*l use infinity free*

If someone could help me and saw this feel free to comment and if you know a pro pleas tell them about this.

Comment: If you cannot create database, how do you want to insert anything to it?

Comment: What don't you know? Can you use any SQL client? PhPMyAdmin for an instance?

Comment: @ryan what do you mean by "When people submit something to the website make a new database" - that sounds like a completely wrong database design

Comment: @NicoHaase and AnnZen Yes, my obvious fault, I'm very sorry, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer** Ryan, your question is very broad and as it doesn't meet StackOveflow's requirements it should be closed, however, there are several lessons you **need** to learn before going further and I hope, that you'll do them properly.

### Lesson 1: MySQL Client

Assuming that you have database MySQL engine instaled, you should use some MySQL client to work with your databases. Note that without installed database engine you **can not** go further! For these purposes you can use:

1. Native `mysql` client in your terminal (cmd in Windows) just by logging to it with the command:

   ```
   mysql -u root -p
   ```
2. GUI client like [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) or [MySQL Workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/). In the next lessons, I will refer to the phpMyAdmin as it's:

   - free of charges
   - OS independent
   - Uses [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface), you can maintain your DB structure and data with graphical interface instead of writing SQL statements manually (which will be in the next lesson)
   - is popular

   If you installed your Apache+MySQL+PHP stack with some application like [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/pl/index.html) most probably you'll find it when opening this address in your browser (check the documentation of your stack for other possibilities):

   - http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

### Lesson 2: Create a database with a table and columns using the GUI client. i.e. phpMyAdmin.

When you located your phpMyAdmin installation log in there with your database credentials, by *click-and-learn* technique learn how to:

1. Create a database(s) with GUI
2. Create a table(s) with GUI
3. Create column(s) with GUI

**TIP:**
As probably you will want your database to accept data with international characters when creating new database always select proper collation for it, I suggest `utf8_general_ci`

**Exercise:**
Just create some sample database, called `my_library` with table `books` and columns:

- `uid` *int*, in GUI check the **A_I** checkbox to make it Auto_Increment and Primary Key
- `title` *varchar(255)*,
- `author_name` *varchar(255)*,
- `publish_year` *int*

**Practise:**

- Creating, updating (altering) and deleting (dropping) databases, tables and columns with GUI.
- Inserting, selecting, updating and deleting (dropping) data in `books` table with GUI.

### Lesson 3: Import/export data using the GUI client. i.e. phpMyAdmin.

If you have a new, blank database created already, click its name in the left pane to go into it and in the right pane at the top, click the **Import** tab. Next, choose the file you want to import (dump import) (**db_google.sql** in your case) and finally click **Go** button at the bottom to upload the file. If your *.sql file is valid database structure will be created. **EndOfMagic!**

You can create your own export *.sql files (dumps) from any existing databases using **Export** tab. Just:

- in left pane click `books` database, we created in the second lesson
- then click **Export** tab at the top of the right pane
- Select: **Export mode:** ***Custom - display all possible options*** for better understanding
- Create a dump to *.sql file or click the option **View output as text** to show the dump in the browser.

**Practise**
Create many dumps of existing database and/or selected tables, by default you'll dump:

- **structure and data** that means that dump will contain the structure of the database to create and data (if any).

Optionally you can create dump with:

- **structure** only
- or **data** only

### Lesson 4: Doing the same with SQL/native SQL client (no GUI).

You can do all the above things in native `mysql` client (mentioned in lesson 1) **OR** in the **SQL** tab of phpMyAdmin using SQL syntax. I.e. to create this database and table(s) using SQL you should send these statements:

```
CREATE DATABASE my_library COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Go to `my_library` in MySQL client by

```
USE my_library;
```

or by clicking it in the left pane of phpMyAdmin

create `books` table with SQL, add keys and insert data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE books (
  uid int(11) NOT NULL,
  title varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  author_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  publish_year int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


ALTER TABLE books ADD PRIMARY KEY (uid);
ALTER TABLE books MODIFY uid int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT INTO books (title, author_name, publish_year) VALUES
    ('The Secret Adversary', 'Agatha Christie', 1922),
    ('Casino Royale', 'Ian Fleming', 1953),
    ('Alice’s Adventures in Wonderland', 'Lewis Carroll', 1865);
```

Then you can check if data where put corectlu with

```sql
SELECT * FROM books WHERE 1;
```

Required output:

```
+-----+------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------+
| uid | title                              | author_name     | publish_year |
+-----+------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------+
|   1 | The Secret Adversary               | Agatha Christie |         1922 |
|   2 | Casino Royale                      | Ian Fleming     |         1953 |
|   3 | Alice’s Adventures in Wonderland   | Lewis Carroll   |         1865 |
+-----+------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------+
```

**Practise**

- Create (`CREATE`)
  [database(s)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-database.html),
  [table(s)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html)
  and column(s) with raw SQL. Note, that columns are created within `CREATE TABLE...`  statement as well.
- Update (`ALTER`)
  [database(s)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-database.html),
  [table(s)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html)
  and column(s) with raw SQL. Note that for altering column(s) you use `ALTER TABLE ...` statement as well.
- Delete (`DROP`)
  [database(s)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/drop-database.html),
  [table(s)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/drop-table.html)
  and column(s). Note you drop the column by [altering the table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html).

### Lesson 5: Accessing and querying MySQL database in PHP.

When you created (or imported) a database already and filled it with some data it's time to access it with PHP. Assuming that you learned previous lessons and created database `my_library` with `books` table and added some records to the books it's time to connect with MySQL from PHP and fetch (and display) some sample data. In this case, I'll show you [**PDO**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) approach which I prefer most, however for learning purposes, you can also try the same with the [**MySQLi**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). let's create `books.php` script:

```php
<?php

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_library;charset=utf8", "your_db_user", "your_password");
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

echo '<h2>Using the `query()` method to find all rows (with no params)</h2>';

$results = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM books WHERE 1");

echo'<ul>';
foreach ($results->fetchAll() as $row){
    echo"<li>Book: '{$row['title']}', by: {$row['author_name']}, published at: {$row['publish_year']}</li>";
}
echo '</ul>';


// OR...
echo '<h2>Using prepared statements with param(s) to find rows which contains 'Secret' word in title</h2>';

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM books WHERE title LIKE :titleSearch");
$stmt->bindValue('titleSearch', '%Secret%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
foreach ($stmt->fetchAll() as $row){
    echo"<li>Book: '{$row['title']}', by: {$row['author_name']}, published at: {$row['publish_year']}</li>";
}
```

Output:

### Using the `query()` method to find all rows (with no params)

- Book: 'The Secret Adversary', by: Agatha Christie, published at: 1922
- Book: 'Casino Royale', by: Ian Fleming, published at: 1953
- Book: 'Alice’s Adventures in Wonderland', by: Lewis Carroll, published at: 1865

### Using prepared statements with param(s) to find rows which contains 'Secret' word in title

- Book: 'The Secret Adversary', by: Agatha Christie, published at: 1922

Remember that for security reasons, using prepared statements is **MUST-HAVE** when working with user's input to prevent [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

### Finally:

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If u have created a database you can export the whole DB to an sql file, but for that you need an already existing database. And if u cant make a database with that name just put an other name and change the database name in the code. Not 100% sure if thats the answer you searched for, if not tell me then i can delete this answer.